# using EXIST in a batch on a file when current directory contains whitespace

Tags: batch

i have a batch file that should work in multiple directories:

it should look for a file called "folder.jpg". If existant, it should use that. if not exist, it should use "front.jpg" and copy it to "cover.jpg". Sounds simple.

The problem is, that my directories contain whitespaces ( -  ).

The following batch file produces an error. Can anyone direct me, how to get a filename that can be used with "EXISTS" batch command?

I also tried "./folder.jpg" with no success.

```
@echo off

set file=%CD%\folder.jpg
set

if exists %file% goto FOLDER

:FRONT
@echo ** copy front.jpg to cover.jpg
copy front.jpg cover.jpg
goto PROCESS

:FOLDER
@echo ** rename folder.jpg to cover.jpg
ren folder.jpg cover.jpg


:PROCESS
@echo ** call dpi
call dpi
@echo ** call size
call size
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try wrapping `%file%` in quotes: `... exists "%file%" ...`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main problem is that the syntax is `IF EXIST` *filename* (that is, no 's'). When file and folder names have spaces, use quote marks.

`set file="%CD%\folder.jpg"`
`if exist %file% goto FOLDER`

or...

`set file=%CD%\folder.jpg`
`if exist "%file%" goto FOLDER`

Also, did you really want the bare `set` command in the third code line? It looks a bit lonely all by itself.

Finally, if you have `@echo off` at the start of the script, you don't need to put the `@` symbol at the start of every `echo` command.

Comment: Thanks! Made my day! 

I tried the quote marks before, and I guess my main prolem was the "s" at EXIST ... the thing is that the error message led me into assuming ther was another problem as it always statet the file name. (like "is not permitted in this context" - translated from German).

And, yep. the set was only during the search of the error ... not needed.
I always do the "@" in fron to echo in case I need to "debug", I comment out echo off, but I do not want to have the doble lines all the time when I echo.

Thanks again!

Comment: I am in the habit of always using quote marks around a file path or name, because if there are no spaces it does not matter. You need the quotes at the point when the file system is used, so you can do `set filename=a file name with spaces` and then later e.g. `type "%filename%"`.